# Conditionally render a badge for active/inactive User

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rendering, class-names

I am trying to render conditionally a badge, based on the `logged` condition of a user. If the props coming from the server is `true`, then the badge is green, `else` grey.

I have tried various solutions, from basic if/else in the JSX, to classNames but the badge isn't being render.

My Code:

```
              {user.loggedIn ? (
                <div
                  className={classNames('badge badge-pill', {
                    'badge-success': user.loggedIn,
                    'badge-danger': !user.loggedIn
                  })}
                />
```

I don't see anything wrong with the code. I mean the item should have rendered, with multiple solutions. Any ideas, what I am doing wrong.

```
              <span
                className={
                  user.loggedIn ? 'badge badge-pill badge-success' : 'badge badge-pill badge-muted'
                }
              />
```

I have tried this as well.

I can see the element in the React-Dev-Tools, being render correctly, witht the right prop, but I cannot see it render in the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your  contents will only get rendered if user is loggedIn. Also the div tag must be closed inside the condition { isLoggedIn }

you should try something like this:

```
        {user.loggedIn ? (
      <div className={'badge badge-pill badge-success'}>ENTER YOUR CONTENT HERE</div>) : (
            <div className={'badge badge-pill badge-danger'}>ENTER YOUR CONTENT HERE</div>
    )}
```

but since the div is self-closing and has no contents, it doesn't display it, so add some content too

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't thinking about content. Now I have to find out how to print a simple circle inside there without content...

Answer (score 0):

The badge for logged out user will never be displayed as you put a rendering condition  around all the div with `user.loggedInd ? (yourComponent...)`

Comment: I posted another solution as well.. Could you explain what is wrong with the second one? If I move the condition inside the div, will that fix it? I think this is what I am doing with the second one.

Comment: The second solution should display a `span` element in the DOM. Then, it's up to the classes you put on it to see if the display is meaningful or not.

Answer (score 0):

If `user.loggedIn` is boolean, then you can just write

```
<div
  className={
    classNames('badge badge-pill', {
      'badge-success': user.loggedIn,
      'badge-danger': user.loggedIn
    })
  }
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to avoid conditional in jsx directly. You can do something like this:

```js
let attachClass = ['badge', 'badge-pill']
   if(user.loggedIn){
      attachClass = [...attachClass, 'badge-success'].join(' ');
   }else{
      attachClass = [...attachClass, 'badge-danger'].join(' ');
   }
```

Than you can just return one div with className attach class:

```js
<div className={attachClass}></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue look into the user.loggedIn is not defined or return false

```
const loggedIn = true;
<span className={loggedIn ? 'badge-success' : 'badge-muted'}>
Css Change </span>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/dwarka/pen/bZoQdm?editors=1100)